# Is there falling damage in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There are a number of tall ledges and cliff faces in the game that you can walk right up to, but the game seems to corral you into the "valid" playing space. Are there any locations or situations that do actually allow you to fall to your death, or at least take some falling damage?

I'd rather not be surprised in the middle of combat by plummeting 30 feet and breaking my Shep-legs.

Comment: While the existing answers are mainly correct there *is* a special case here for the effect of biotics...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no fall damage.  You have to "sprint" as you approach certain jump points (indicated by a translucent blue arrow).  If you walk up to these areas without sprinting, you'll just stop as if you reached the end of the world.

There's no way to plummet to your doom under normal situations.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there are no ledges that can be walked off of that cause fall damage.  As you said, the game prevents the player from walking off most ledges.  When the player is instructed to jump across ledges, the sprint button must be held down or a similar blocking will occur.

**Edit** Apparently there are bugs that allow shepard to fall off cliffs.  Thanks to [TylerShads](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/18943/tylershads) for posting these [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3795862#3795862)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to pause and recover for a while after falling off high ledges as compared to sliding down a ladder. You take no damage, but the pause can be deadly if you are under fire.